# How to communicate between typescript decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

To learn more about decorators I would like to create a decorator which caches the output of a function, something like this

```
class BarFoo {
    @Cahced()
    doComplexCalc(@CahcedParamIgnore() a, b, c) {

    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zwni4f?file=index.ts,cache-decorator.ts,cache-param-ignore.ts,index.html)

The `@Cached` decorator caches the response from `doComplexCalc` based on the values from `a`, `b` and `c`. As you can see in the example, I would also like to be able to ignore one or more method arguments. My question is, what would be the best way for the `@CahcedParamIgnore` decorator to inform the `@Cached` decorator about which arguments to ignore?

Comment: Decorators are typescript exlusive.

Comment: You would use [reflect-metadata](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) as seen in this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) from the TypeScript docs.

Comment: They are in Stage 3 as an Ecmascript proposal - https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators

Comment: Thnx @KonradLinkowski I updated my title!

Comment: And thnx @caTS for the suggestion!